# switch_to_blog errors when connecting to another wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I have created a function within my Wordpress theme that allows the site to connect to a second multisite installation (the "Hub") and grab our staff directory, emergency alert information, and headline news. The second multisite is broken down into several blogs:

Emergency notifications: Site 2
Campus Directory: Site 3
Events Calendar: Site 4
News: Site 5
Dining Calendar: Site 6

You can see them all in action at http://inside.scrippscollege.edu

The problem comes when this site and our new external site share a blog_id. For example, Site 3 (our Faculty page) on Inside Scripps and Site 3 (Emergency Response) on the external staging site cannot run the directory function properly because they all use the same blog_id. I don't know how to work around this problem, or even troubleshoot it.

The function begins like this:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb_backup = $wpdb; // Copies the global Wordpress variables for later
$wpdb = new wpdb('XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX');
$wpdb->set_prefix('wp_');
$wpdb->show_errors();

global $blog_id;
global $switched;

switch_to_blog(3);  // Switches over the the directory portion of the Hub
```

After running my query, I end the function as so:

```
restore_current_blog();  // Restores the switch_to_blog() function
$wpdb = $wpdb_backup;  // Restores the global Wordpress variables
return $output;
```

If I define DIEONDBERROR at the top, I'll get an error like this:

WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE option_name = 'category_children' LIMIT 1 /* From [SITE' at line 1] SELECT option_value FROM WHERE option_name = 'category_children' LIMIT 1 /* From [SITE/emergency/] in [/functions/office.php:65] */

Line 65 is where I start my argument:

```
$news_posts = new WP_Query( $args ); // Select posts we're going to use
```

So, is there a step I'm missing where I switch to the blog but keep the blog_id so the integrity of the search is maintained? I have a nagging suspicion this glitch is contributing to similar errors where the sites with matching blog_ids will stop working until I clear our host's cache.

Comment: Read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/89113/12615) and also try to use [get_posts instead of wp_query](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1753/12615). Also, I'd try  to create a new object and leave $wpdb alone.